# Video doesn't show

Tags: android, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>DDK</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Door Darshan India</h1>
        <image src="ddk.jpg" width="460">
        </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#page2">Bidushi M.S.Subbulaxmi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Ustad Bismillah Khan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Bharatnatyam</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5">Kathak</a></li>
            <li><a href="page6">Odissi</a></li>
            <li><a href="page7">Kathakali</a></li>
            <li><a href="page8">Manipuri</a></li> 
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>M.S.Subhalaxmi</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    <video width="420" height="340" controls>

    <source src="Subhalaxmi.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="Subhalaxmi.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'></video>

    </div>


    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Ustad Bismillah Khan</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    <video width="420" height="340" controls>
    <video src="Bismilla Khan.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="Bismilla Khan.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'></video>
    </div>




    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    </div>




<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bharatnatyam</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
    <video width="420" height="340" controls>

    <video src="Bharatnatyam.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
     <source src="Bharatnatyam.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

    </video>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page5">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div align="justify"></div>
        <h1>Kathak</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page6">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Odissi</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page7">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Kathakali</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page8">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Manipuri</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Except the video on `"page2"` no other video plays. Only the controls are seen on `"page3"` and `"page4"`. All the video files are in the same folder.

Where am I going wrong ? Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 times the same error.

```
<**video** src="Bharatnatyam.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
 <source src="Bharatnatyam.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

</video>
```

Should be

```
<**source** src="Bharatnatyam.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
 <source src="Bharatnatyam.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

</video>
```

Also on page 3.
(Without the '**' of course)

Comment: Thanks so much. How I missed it!

Comment: Now I have made an apk in eclipse with same  source code. Installed it on my  android phone (Galaxy Note II). The video window with all the controls  loads including the play button but the videos don't play.  All I see is a black screen. Problem with OS itself or something other?

Comment: Different devices support different codecs, it might be a device or os specific issue, try to test it on other devices as well.

Comment: Check also here for example http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/ though it might be a bit outdated.

Comment: @RanjanMitra If my answer helped you, you can mark it so other users know it is the solution. Thanks!